# HeightRequest on ListView calculates weird?

Tags: xamarin

I've heard a couple things about `ListView`.

- it takes up the full height of its container
- on iOS it just goes ahead and adds empty rows until it takes up the full height
- you have to use `HasUnevenRows=True` to be able to set its height even if all your rows are the same height.

It sure would be great if there were a way to get `ListView` to not display those extra empty rows though, right? Well, that's what I am trying to do.

```
<ListView 
    BackgroundColor="Green"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    HeightRequest="5"> <!-- In the real code I am setting this in a ValueConverter. It's hard coded here for simplicity. -->
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="This is text." />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Except I don't even know what it could possibly be doing. Here I use `HeightRequest=5` and `HeightRequest=50` there is a difference. But I can't tell what it is.

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Now this is a very interesting question. We have had similar issues with ListViews as unfortunately that unlimited scrolling is actually a standard behaviour on iOS, so you have to think of way around it. The way we have done it is basically count the amount of items within the list, this is pretty straight forward, because you only have to call for `ListOfItems.Count`. Next thing you want to do, you want to get the Height of your Single DataTemplate item. When you do that then just multiple count of your items by Height of single item and set that Value to `HeightRequest`. It is not ideal, but it does a job.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. Do you set the `HeightRequest` on the `ListView` directly? It seems to work if I nest it inside a `StackLayout`. How do you handle lists that are taller than the available screen space?

Comment: @user875234 No, you only need to get a Height of DataTemplate, which would be the size of your ViewCell (i assume this by looking at your code above). You can get that by giving name x:Name to your ViewCell and then in xaml.cs call for:
var cellheight = ViewCellName.Height;

Comment: And sorry yes, you set HeightRequest on your ListView. In regards the size of the list that are bigger than size of the screen, that is the point of ListView, if items are bigger than available space, you will be able just to scroll it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why this works. What I don't understand is why the 50 other ways I tried did not work. So from that point of view I have no idea why this works.

Wrap it in a `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView 
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        HeightRequest="5"> <!-- In the real code I am setting this in a ValueConverter. It's hard coded here for simplicity. -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="This is text." />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

It might seem relevant at first but I'm not sure. My `ListView` was in a grid so it had

```
<ListView
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="1"
    ... />
```

Which got moved into the `StackLayout`. Again, I know that seems glaringly relevant but I have my doubts. Unfortunately I don't have the time to rip everything out just to test that idea out.